# How can I demonstrate this series are the same?

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

How can I know that they are equivalent?

$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} e^{-n^2\pi x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}e^{\frac{-n^2\pi}{x}} $$

I find this in wikipedia, in an article about the gamma function, where they used this property to find the analytic continuation of the zeta function.
Thank you.

Comment: Poisson summation formula?

Comment: Maybe that can work